# Run Powershell script on selected instance in CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a CloudFormation where:

1. An instance is selected
2. The CloudFormation template has inputs that are to be used in the script
3. Executes this script into the selected instance

How do I execute a Powershell script from CloudFormation?

Comment: What do you mean by "an instance is selected"? CloudFormation can create _new_ resources and you can specify properties for the new resource, but it cannot perform operations on an _existing_ instance.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein A dropdown for an existing instance ID is on the CloudFormation template and then the script is executed on that instance

Comment: Oh! No, that is not possible using CloudFormation. It can _create new resources_, but cannot modify existing resources. If you wish to run a script on an existing Amazon EC2 instance, consider using [AWS Systems Manager Run Command - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a PowerShell script via the User Data. It will be executed on the first startup of the instance.

Here is an example script:

```
<powershell>
$file = $env:SystemRoot + "\Temp\" + (Get-Date).ToString("MM-dd-yy-hh-mm")
New-Item $file -ItemType file
</powershell>
```

See: [Running Commands on Your Windows Instance at Launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html)